# Finding the expectancy of a distribution function

Tags: probability, expectation

I have the function below and I'm trying to calculate the expectancy of X. The answer is E(X) = $\frac{59}{40}$ but I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I cannot achieve it.

F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ < 0} \\
\frac{1}{4}, & \text{if 0 $\le$ $x$ < 1} \\
\frac{2}{5}, & \text{if 1 $\le$ $x$ < 2} \\
\frac{2x-3}{2}, & \text{if 2 $\le$ $x$ < 2.5} \\
1,  & \text{if $x$ $\ge$ 2.5} \\
\end{cases}

I did like that

$$E(X) = \frac{1}{4}*1 + \frac{2}{5}*1 + \int_2^{2.5} \frac{2x-3}{2} dx$$

which gave me thw wrong answer. I'm sure if the problem is in the computation of the integral (I'm a little bit rusty in calculus) or of the problem is the concept of my calculations as a whole

Comment: I don't understand why both 1/4 and 2/5 are multiplied by $1$...

Comment: For starters, 1/4 is the probability the random variable is 0, not 1.  2/5 - 1/4 is the probability it is 1.

Comment: $1$ for $x\ge2.5$? Then your distribution is not normalized. Should it be $0$ if $x\ge2.5$?

Comment: No, it's 1 for $x$ $\ge$ 2.5

Comment: As indicated the function $F$ given is a CDF but not a pmf or pdf. So you may use $\int_0^{+\infty}(1 - F(x))dx$ to get the expectation. Or you follow the normal route to get the pmf/pdf first and do summation/integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the Cumulative distribution function you have there not the probability density function. You have to convert the CDF first if you want to calculate the expected value of $X$. Or use

$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X (x)) \, dx = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{59}{40}$$

Comment: Can you explain further? I didn't understand exactly how you get these numbers. Do you did like that? $\int_0^1 (1-\frac{1}{4}) \, dx + \int_1^2 (1-\frac{2}{5}) \, dx + \int_2^{2.5} (1-\frac{2x-3}{2}) \, dx$ ? I'm rusty in calculus and I'm struggling I little to understand what you did

Comment: @Rods2292 Yes, that is exactly what i did.

Comment: This answer is wrong, but it is marked as accepted and appears before the correct answer (by Joseph), which can be confusing to the readers. What can be done?

Answer (score 4):

This is a mixed distribution to begin with. It has atoms at $0$, $1$ and $2$, meaning that the cumulative distribution function jumps at these points. To calculate the expected value of such a distribution, you would like to look at 
$$
E[X] = \sum_{x_i \mbox{ is a mass point}}^{}p_i x_i + \int_{x \mbox{ is not a mass point}} x f(x) dx
$$
So here, the mass points are $x\in \{0,1,2\}$ such that $p(0)=1/4$, $p(1)=2/5$ and $p(2)=1/2-2/5=1/10$. When $x\in [2,2.5)$, $f(x)=F'(x)=1$. Therefore, your answer is 
$$
E[X] = 0\times 1/4+1\times 2/5+2\times 1/10+\int_2^{2.5}x \frac{2x-3}{2}dx  = \frac{59}{40} 
$$

Comment: I didn't understand this passage of you answer: "p(2)=1/2−2/5=1/10". Can you explain further? Where does 2/5 comes from?

Comment: p(2) means the probability that the outcome is x=2. Note that $P(x<2)=2/5$ and $P(x\leq 2) = F(2)=1/2$. Thus, $P(x=2) = P(x\leq 2)-P(x< 2)$.